# Aplicativo da StackExchange para Windows Store?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Já ouvi falar que existe um aplicativo oficial da StackExchange feito pela própria empresa para o Android, e o coitado do Windows 10? Esqueceram dele? Você que esta lendo isso está usando um Windows, por quê não faz um abaixo assinado para **criarem um aplicativo oficial da StackExchange para Windows 10 e Windows 10 Mobile?**

## *Ha há, Windows Phone não tem apps!*

Eu sou usuário de Windows e me deparo com essa triste realidade, queria muito poder criar respostas para o **StackOverflow PT** pelo meu Lumia. Seria uma atitude muito boa e caridosa para todos!

> ### Gabe nos ajude!
>
> Faça suas mágicas e por favor, peça à equipe da StackExchange para fazer um aplicativo oficial, ou que liberem uma API para alguém com vontade (*Hehe estou disponível*) para fazer um aplicativo faça um com qualidade... Obrigado!

Comment: Se quiser se aventurar, [a API já existe](https://api.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: [**O Gabe meio que já falou sobre o assunto**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3928/por-qu%c3%aa-o-app-do-stackexchange-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-divulgado-no-site/3930#comment10456_3930).

Comment: @bfavaretto me desculpe a ignorância, mas essa API se encaixa em qual plataforma? o.O

Comment: Qualquer plataforma. Você acessa a API por meio de requisições HTTP.

Comment: A última vez que vi algo sobre o assunto, foi que não tinham previsão para fazer uma(nem de 6-8 a semanas =\\) [Does Stack Overflow have a Windows Phone app?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274379/1342547). Também uso wp8.

Comment: 6-8 semanas = 6-8 anos

Comment: Achei um cliente do StackExchange para Windows Phone, ta ai o Link https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/store/apps/stack-mate/9nblggh0jf49 :D

Comment: Ah, essa mágica aí nem eu... Uma vez eu perguntei de curiosidade e riram da minha cara. Mas como o @bfavaretto falou, a API tá aí!

Comment: Acho que é mais vantajoso criar um repositório e mandar ver. Quem sabe o app fica bom, se torna oficial e até te convidam pra trabalhar com eles hahahaha.

Comment: Quero ver é ânimo pra entender uma API complicada dessas :P

Comment: `estou disponivel` vs `api complicada`, talvez encontre exemplos funcionais aqui: http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7

Comment: Ou podes sempre usar o browser que é muito melhor que a app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Stackie](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stackie/9nblggh6gzv5)

<sup>[Detalhes do aplicativo.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/stackie/9nblggh6gzv5#app-details) - criado para Windows 10.</sup>

---

## [Heep](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/heep/9nblgggz5qgk)

<sup>[Detalhes do aplicativo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/heep/9nblgggz5qgk#app-details) - criado para Windows 10.</sup>

---

## [StackMate](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/store/apps/stack-mate/9nblggh0jf49)

<sup>[Detalhes do aplicativo.](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/store/apps/stack-mate/9nblggh0jf49#app-details)</sup>

Comment: O Heep tem uma excelente interface, bonita simples, com um bom tamanho e boa organização, ótimos links!

Comment: Achei o stackie meio bagunçado, mas o heep realmente é muito bonito.

Comment: Infelizmente o heep não fornece acesso ao SOPT.

Answer (score 3):

Se eu tivesse poderes mágicos, todo mundo na empresa falaria português e o SOpt teria muito mais recursos do que tem hoje! Na verdade, é mais provável que eu estivesse na minha ilha flutuante, cercado de guitarras e não precisando trabalhar. Mas ia tomar conta do SOpt antes de largar tudo pra dar show no céu, com certeza.

De qualquer maneira, posso afirmar categoricamente que não há plano nenhum de um aplicativo do SO/SE para Windows, telefone ou desktop. A equipe Mobile é bem enxuta, e precisa lidar com o que é fundamental antes de se meter em novos e mirabolantes projetos. Há bastante a ser feito nos aplicativos que já temos (*inclusive internacionalização*) e não há como fazer mais nada por enquanto.